# Need help with some C# Counting Code

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a counter in Ninjatrader which uses C# as its programming language.

I would like this counter to commence counting upon the completion of the first counter and once it commences counting to consider only the new condition when counting.

So, the first counter commences when Close[0] < Close[4]. The second counter commences ONLY after the first counter has reached 9 and its condition for counting is Close[0] <= Low[2].

I don't know how to write the part of the code where the second counter commences counting and its counts are independent of the first counter reaching 9.

Answer (score 0):

When does the first counter reset ?

If it does not reset, you can store the CurrentBar when  Close[0] < Close[4] and add that number to CurrentBar going forward. Then do the same for the second counter.